# handling to onchange event of AutoCompleteTextField in wicket

Tags: java, web-applications, autocomplete, wicket

I'm writing an autocomplete component for a webapp using Java and Wicket.

Is there a way to handle the onchange event to run some code when the user selects one of the options of the autocomplete list? I tried doing this in the AutoCompleteTextField:

```
        setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onchange") {
            @Override
            protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                System.out.println(getInput());
            }
        });
```

But the getInput method returns null. :(
Is there a way to react to the onchange event and to be able to read what the user has entered?

Thanks for you time and knowledge :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>The `onchange` event is only fired when the focus is moved away from the component. (This is a universal browser/javascript thing.)</strike>

You need to hook your handler to the `onkeypress` event instead.

What you need is not `AjaxEventBehavior` but `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`:

```
    add( new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior( "onchange") {

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            System.out.println( "Value: "+field.getValue() );

        }
    });
```

Although it works with `getInput()` too, but usually the somewhat higher level (properly escaped and backed by the model) `getValue()` is a better fit.

Comment: Hmm I don't think so... The problem is not that the method is not called, but that the wicket component AutoCompleteTextField returns null as its input. Anyway I'll try what you say.

Comment: that is correct, thanks, but now I'm having another problem. Please check this question, if you have the time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226492/using-autocompletetextfield-in-wicket-without-string-as-the-generic-type