# using AutoCompleteTextField in wicket without String as the generic type

Tags: java, web-applications, autocomplete, wicket

This question follows this: [handling to onchange event of AutoCompleteTextField in wicket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223610/handling-to-onchange-event-of-autocompletetextfield-in-wicket)

I'm trying to use the AutoCompleteTextField with a custom class as the generic type, and to add an AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior. What I mean is I want to have a

```
AutoCompleteTextField<SomeClass> myAutoComplete = ...;
```

and after that add a AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior:

```
myAutoComplete.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            System.out.println( "Value: "+getValue() );

        }
    });
```

The problem is that for some reason, adding that behavior makes the form try to set the model object with a String (even though the AutoCompleteTextField has a generic type of SomeClass), causing a ClassCastException when the onchange event fires.

Is there a way to use `AutoCompleteTextField` without it being `AutoCompleteTextField<String>`? I couldn't find any example. Thanks for your time!

and thanks to the user [biziclop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574479/biziclop) for his help in this matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is unrelated to the event handler, it is caused by the lack of a model type set in your component.

Form components can derive the model type from 3 sources:

1. Resolve it automatically if you're using a `PropertyModel` or a `CompoundPropertyModel`.
2. Accept it as an additional constructor parameter.
3. Via the `setType()` method.
4. (If none of the above apply, the default behaviour is to use String, or Boolean for checkboxes.)

These are your options, you can choose any of the three, but I think 1 is better than 2, which is better than 3.

**Update:** You probably already know this but if your custom class is really custom, you'll also need an `IConverter` that handles the String<->Someclass conversions: you can either register it with the application or override your component's `getConverter(Class<?> clazz )` method to return it.

Comment: But he is using method 1 with (AutoCompleteTextField<SomeClass> myAutoComplete) ?

Comment: @bert Unfortunately, no. Wicket only resolves type information from models that implement `IObjectClassAwareModel`.

Comment: that Update was the key. Thanks!